# One liner with haskell.nix

Tags: haskell, nix

How can one do a one liner with a precise set of dependency from stackage, like one can do with the nixpkgs head ?

```sh
nix shell --impure --expr "with import <nixpkgs> { };haskellPackages.ghcWithPackages(p: with p; [network HTTP conduit conduit-extra])" --command runghc -v helloworld.hs
```

VS

```sh
nix shell github:??/stackage?#lts-18.23? --command runghc -v myfile.hs
```

(edit : replaced old style command with nested bash as tipped in remark)

```sh
$(nix-build -E "with import <nixpkgs> { };haskellPackages.ghcWithPackages(p: with p; [network HTTP conduit conduit-extra])")/bin/runghc -v myfile.hs
```

Comment: You can use the same call to `ghcWithPackages` with `nix shell -p` that you use with `nix-build`. Or are you asking about using `stackage` *instead* of `nixpkgs`?

Comment: Indeed, I would like the program myfile.hs to use the dependencies from stackage, from the Haskel.nix infrastructure https://github.com/input-output-hk/haskell.nix whose flake contains the attribute set from stackage https://github.com/input-output-hk/stackage.nix